# I can't access NEXTAUTH_URL since I can't access it with NEXT_PUBLIC

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-auth

In NextJS you have to add `NEXT_PUBLIC_` to env variables to make them available to the browser, but "next-auth" only accepts hard coded variables like `NEXTAUTH_URL`, is there anyway to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Environment variables prefixed with `NEXT_PUBLIC_` will be inlined in the application bundle. `NEXTAUTH_URL` isn't used in the bundle. It is used by the API routes to handle the redirect URL. That means you must define it in [Vercel](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables#environment-variables-on-vercel).

Comment: am running the app on localhost, I haven't hosted it so I can't add the env variables using vercel dashboard

Comment: The you define them in a `.env.local` file as shown here https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables#loading-environment-variables

Comment: I did, I've even tried with next.config.js `module export` & restarting after making changes, but still keep getting this error `warnings#nextauth_url NEXTAUTH_URL environment variable not set`

Comment: Update, fixed the issue by reverting to using `.env.local` instead of `next.config.js` . Even though `next.config.js` works with other env variables, it seems not to work with `NEXTAUTH_URL`. The issue wasn't to do with `NEXT_PUBLIC_` either, since I've not added it to `NEXTAUTH_URL` and the app is now working, which makes sense because you actually don't need to expose `NEXTAUTH_URL` to the browser

Comment: @AndrewGillis should `NEXTAUTH_URL` be defined on build when compiling for production or I can leave it undefined on build and set it just in runtime?